# Using CMD to fire SQL rename stored procedure returns warning, stops script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, batch-file, cmd

I have a `.BAT` file that executes a few commands. Everything works fine until the `SP_Rename`, I get the following message returned:

> Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.

And my next line on the CMD prompt window shows: `1>` with a cursor. It should be executing the next line of code, but it does not.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: can you please post the code of the `.bat` script? I have a feeling that something else is going on as that message is just a warning and should not be having any effect on the script.

Answer (score 2):

The message raised is `Select * from sys.messages where message_id=15477`.
You could get the procedure text via `EXEC sp_helptext sp_rename`,
remove  the line  `raiserror(15477,-1,-1)` and create a new procedure e.g. sp_rename_no_alert and use this for your batch operations.

Answer (score 0):

How is your .BAT file structured? Is it a bunch of separate SQLCMD invocations one after the other, and it stops after the first one by leaving you at the "1>" prompt?

If that's the case, I don't think the caution is what is causing SQLCMD to leave you at the prompt. -Q (uppercase) instead of the `-q` parameter for running your query, as the lowercase `-q` will leave you at the prompt and wait for more input.

Example:

```
SQLCMD -Q "exec sp_rename(blah)"
```